Hausdorff's Division of the Circle into Congruent Pieces
I was reading Andersen & Jessen's (1948) "On the Introduction of Measures in Infinite Product Sets", where they provide an example of an infinite product that can't be assigned a countably additive measure (i.e. a space for which the Kolmogorov Extension Theorem fails– see this post).
Beginning in section 4 on page 5, they write:

Let $C$ denote a circle of length $1$... Let $C$ be divided in Hausdorff's manner into disjoint sets $\cdots, C_{-1}, C_0, C_1, \cdots$ which are congruent by rotation.

I can't seem to find any references to this "Hausdorff division" of the circle into countably many congruent pieces. Does anyone know what this is referring to?

Is it possible that this is referring to what we now call the Vitali set? (ie, think of the circle as $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$ and take $C_0$ to be a set of coset representatives for $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$). It seems that it must be something a bit like this, as $C_0$ cannot have a sensible one-dimensional Lebesgue measure.

I think you might be right. I just found these notes which describe the Andersen Jessen construction using a nonmeasurable set $V$ by taking representatives from $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ and attributes the construction to van Vleck (no mention of Hausdorff though). It has a very similar flavour to the Vitali set. I'm going to read carefully and will post here if I find a good answer.
